# Creating a stand alone GUI which shows interactive matplotlib figures

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

I'm looking to build a stand-alone tool (preferably EXE) that will take on a text file of specific format and plot it's content in a figure. The exe will launch a GUI in which the user will have to press a button and browse the OS to choose a file. once a file was chosen, the user will select the columns of interest and will press a "Go" button. after pressing, an interactive matplotlib figure will be plotted on the GUI canvas in a specific section.

The user will be able to zoom in and out, to add graphs and remove graphs as needed. 
How easy it is to write something like that in python?
What are the topics one has to familiar with to do such app?
What is the framework/IDE I want to use for developing such app?
Is there an existing code that does something similar from which i can start?

All info will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had quite a lot of success with mixing matplotlib and the Qt-framework, using PyQt4.

I used [this tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Qt_with_IPython_and_Designer) but I guess there are others.
Working with the Qt API is quite straight-forward, and there is QtDesigner that helps you build your interface.
With Qt you will also be able to keep your application cross-platform without trouble.

Comment: Me too, even though i prefer writing the gui without the designer because i don't like it to much.

Comment: As a side note, we are working on making this easier from the API side. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2624  If you have opinions, please chime in on github.

Comment: @tcaswell, interesting! I am afraid I don't have anything to add, but I am happy to see work on making embedding mpl in GUIs could get easier :)

Comment: Even a description of how you use the embedding or how you wish it worked would be great.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with github, drop me an email (see my profile for address)

Comment: I'll think about it, and yes, I use github :)

Comment: Have you been able to create stand alone executables?  Matplotlib seems to cause many issues when using pyinstaller...